# Let $C$ be an $n\times n$ matrix such that $C^2=0$. Is it necessary for $C$ to be a null matrix?

Tags: matrices

I know that according to the property if $n \times n$ matrices $A$ and $B$ are such that $AB=0$ then there is two cases: either $A$ is invertible and $B$ is the null matrix or $A$ and $B$ both are singular. But does that hold even when $A=B$?
I tried proving it using variable but it ended up with a mess of cubics.

Comment: What about $\left(\begin{smallmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{smallmatrix}\right)$?

Comment: A more general counterexample for $n=2$ is $$\pmatrix {a&a\\-a&-a}$$ for every real number $a$.

Comment: There are three cases, not two: it might be that $A$ is the null matrix and $B$ is invertible.

Comment: For $n>2$ , a simple counterexample is any nonzero matrix $C$ in which the element $c_{11}$ and all other elements apart from those in the first row are $0$.

Comment: $\det(C^2) = 0 \Rightarrow \det(C) = 0 \Rightarrow C$ is singular is I think the best you can do here.

Comment: @Peter But for $n=2$ all such matrices are similar to the first counterexample, see [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1268533/show-that-a-nonzero-2-times-2-matrix-a-such-that-a2-0-is-similar-to?rq=1).

Comment: @DerekAllums If $C$ is regular, we can also multiply $C^2=0$ with $C^{-1}$ (from the left or from the right , that does here not matter) to get $C=0$. But your proof that $C$ must be singular is nice as well.

Comment: No it implies that C is singular. The square of a non zero matrix may be a zero matrix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comments give a variety of $2 \times 2$ examples, but in the hope a geometric perspective is helpful: The $(i, j)$ entry of a matrix product $AB$ is the product of the $i$th row of $A$ and the $j$th column of $B$, i.e., the Euclidean dot product of the $i$th column of $A^t$ (the transpose of $A$) and the $j$th column of $B$.

Consequently, $C^{2} = 0$ if and only if every row of $C$ is orthogonal to every column of $C$, if and only if the row space of $C$ is orthogonal to the column space, if and only if the column space of $C$ is contained in the nullspace of $C$. (Particularly, if $C$ is $n \times n$, then $2\operatorname{rank}(C) \leq n$.)